# symbol(s) not found in architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, macos

I am getting this "symbol(s) not found in architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)." Actually, these messages didn't appear until I upgraded to macOS Mojave.

The complete message I got is:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /Users/suraj/Desktop/sfm/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/sfm obj/Debug/main.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::RenderStates::Default", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)", 
referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, 
 unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Color::Green", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned 
char)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Shape::~Shape()", referenced from:
  sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape() in main.o
"sf::String::String(char const*, std::__1::locale const&)", referenced 
from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Window::close()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Window::display()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)", 
referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"sf::Window::isOpen() const", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code is:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: The actual error message will tell you exactly (and often with brutal, soul-crushing detail that goes on for pages and pages) what was missing. We need to see that actual error message (or the first few entries at least should it go on for pages and pages) to be able to offer much help to you.

Comment: I have posted the complete message now.

Comment: Thank you. It also included the build commands which were even more useful. In `g++  -o bin/Debug/sfm obj/Debug/main.o` there should be also be a `-L<path to SFML  library folder>`, `-lsfml-graphics`, a `-lsfml-window` and probably a `-lsfml-system`. Sadly I don't know what build tool you're using so I can't recommend how best to add them.

Comment: I have no Mad Macs skills, but perhaps https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php will help.

Comment: Did you install `sfml` using **homebrew**?

Comment: yes i installed sfml with homebrew

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer - May 2019**

It seems that the `openal` package is no longer in **homebrew** and that causes the instructions below to fail. I don't know the background behind it. Here is another approach.

You can find all the `pkg-config` related parts of `sfml` like this:

```
find /usr/local/Cellar/sfml -name \*pc

/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-network.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-all.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-graphics.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-audio.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-system.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib/pkgconfig/sfml-window.pc
```

It seems you cannot use `sfml-all` nor `sfml-audio` in the above list, so you will need to pick which parts you want to use and grab them individually, so if you want `graphics`, `window` and `system`:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-graphics
-I/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include 
-I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-system
-I/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib -lsfml-system

pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-window
-I/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include
-L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

So, you would compile with:

```
g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-window sfml-system sfml-graphics) -o main
```

**Original Answer**

If you installed **sfml** via **homebrew**, I would suggest you also install `pkg-config` like this:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Then you can get the switches needed to compile with:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-all
```

**Sample Output**

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -lsfml-system
```

So you can compile with:

```
g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-all) -o main
```

Comment: None of these commands worked for me, any alternative solutions?

Comment: @EddyEkofo I had another look and updated my answer. If that doesn't work, please open a new question (questions are free) with all the diagnostics and error messages and add a note here linking to it - get the link by clicking `share` under your new question and copying the link.

Comment: here is the Qs: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973407/fatal-error-sfml-system-hpp-file-not-found ]. Any help would be appreciated.