# Is there a way to link SFML libraries in VSCode Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, sfml

Is there a reasonably easy to follow way to link SFML libraries with VSCode in macOS?

My case:

- Using Mac
- Using Clang with VSCode
- Have Xcode installed
- Am an amateur

*Note : I am using clang and Mac*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i link the SFML libraries in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404670/how-do-i-link-the-sfml-libraries-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

See my question and answer here: [Manually link and compile C++ program with SFML (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162827/manually-link-and-compile-c-program-with-sfml-macos)

In a nutshell:

- download sfml for mac
- copy include directory from extracted folder to your project directory
- copy the dynamic library files to your project also, folder lib
- in terminal type the g++ command and link to the dynamic libs

It will be something like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I include -L lib -l sfml-system -l sfml-window -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-audio -l sfml-network -Wl,-rpath ./lib
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a boiler plate to link sfml in vs code:

https://github.com/andrew-r-king/sfml-vscode-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

If you have Macbook M1, the other answers won't work. The reason is because sfml from the website is compiled in x86_64, and you can't compile the libraries directly to arm64. So, you need `sfml` and `pkg-config` to be installed on Homebrew.

Command:

```
g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-window sfml-system sfml-graphics) -o main
```

More detailed solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510642/16264548

If you don't wan to use `pkg-config`, then you can manually type in the locations:

```
main.cpp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the editor features, you can add library include files to C/C++ configurations:

- Open Command Palette (⇧⌘P by default)
- Type and select **"C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)"**
- In section **"Include path"** add a line: `/your/path/to/sfml/include/*`

In my case, the path is `/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/include/*`