# fatal error: SFML/System.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, visual-studio-code, sfml

I am trying to work with SMFL, CMAKE & VSCode. Cmake cannot link these SFML files. I install SFML & CMake using Homebrew.

I have tried including the SFML files with `SMFL_ROOT` & `SFML_INCLUDE_DIR` to no avail.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.2)
project(WordTypeCpp VERSION 0.1.0 )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics system)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    set(SFML_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include/SFML/")
# include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include")
endif(SFML_FOUND)

set(SOURCE_FILES Main.cpp)
add_executable(Main ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Main ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

add_definitions(-include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/PCH.hpp)

include(CPack)
```

My `Main.cpp` file

```
#include "PCH.hpp"
#include "Main.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "SFML is running!" << '\n';

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
#ifdef SFML_SYSTEM_WINDOWS
    __windowsHelper.setIcon(window.getSystemHandle());
#endif

    sf::CircleShape shape(window.getSize().x / 2);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

    sf::Texture shapeTexture;
    shapeTexture.loadFromFile("content/sfml.png");
    shape.setTexture(&shapeTexture);

    sf::Event event;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
// PCH.hpp file
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
```

```
--config Debug --target Main -- -j 6
[build] [1/2  50% :: 1.825] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: src/CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main.cpp.o 
[build] /usr/bin/clang++    -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -include /Users/.../WordTypeCpp/src/PCH.hpp -std=gnu++1z -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/Main.dir/Main.cpp.o -c ../src/Main.cpp
[build] In file included from <built-in>:1:
[build] /Users/.../WordTypeCpp/src/PCH.hpp:11:10: fatal error: 'SFML/System.hpp' file not found
[build] #include <SFML/System.hpp>
[build]          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to search for includes and your linker where to search for libraries.

Comment: Thank you @JesperJuhl, how do I do that? Any examples. I am new to this.

Comment: You can do that with `target_include_directories(Main ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies on this line:

```
target_link_libraries(Main ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

This won't propagate requirements properly. It will only link the sfml libraries. Usually you also want other requirement such as include directories.

Instead, you should link to the targets exported by sfml:

```
target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE sfml-graphics sfml-system)
```

Also you shouldn't need that:

```
# uneeded
if (SFML_FOUND)
    set(SFML_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include/SFML/")
    # include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include")
endif(SFML_FOUND)
```

Comment: Merci and thank you.. Saved me hours of unnecessary hacking.

Comment: can you explain how to get around this with node-gyp?

Comment: @JacobSchneider ask a new question for this