# I Can't compile c++ with SFML library by gcc

Tags: c++, sfml, ld, fedora

so first there is a file named main.cpp and I want to compile it using this:
`g++ -o sfml_example main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

btw this is the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Window");
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and when I tried to compile it, it just said this:
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-system: No such file or directory collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I also try this input:
`g++ -v -o sfml_example main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

and it prints out this output:

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,m2,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --with-libstdcxx-zoneinfo=/usr/share/zoneinfo --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-13.2.1-20231011/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-offload-defaulted --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.1 20231011 (Red Hat 13.2.1-4) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'sfml_example' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'sfml_example-'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpdir sfml_example- -dumpbase main.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o /tmp/ccDQjcr6.s
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 13.2.1 20231011 (Red Hat 13.2.1-4) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 13.2.1 20231011 (Red Hat 13.2.1-4), GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.2.0-p12, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../include/c++/13
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../include/c++/13/x86_64-redhat-linux
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../include/c++/13/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: eec6ea8c5ebefd8c87c81ea2002f55e3
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'sfml_example' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'sfml_example-'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccsGUG0P.o /tmp/ccDQjcr6.s
GNU assembler version 2.40 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.40-13.fc39
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'sfml_example' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'sfml_example.'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccw87IFm.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o sfml_example /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../.. /tmp/ccsGUG0P.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-system: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to located where is the lsfml files, and I found it at /lib64
Note: I'm using Fedora Linux Workspace Version 39

So, please any people that can find the solution how to succeded to compile the code would send the solutions.
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `-L /lib64`

Comment: `gcc -L/lib64 -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system main7.cpp -o main7`
still have the same output as before

Comment: If your code is C++, use `g++ main7.cpp ...`

Comment: ah yeah I'm using c++, but the output still like as before even I use g++

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you have done already looks reasonable, however the linker which is a part of your compiler toolchain is for some reason unable to find the compiled library files. What does `ls /lib64/libsfml-graphics.*` print? What architecture is the machine you are compiling on?

Comment: Thanks for your concerns. I have checked that the SFML libraries are installed in /lib64 and my machine is x86_64. I’ve tried the '-L /lib64' flag, but the issue persists. Could there be any configuration issues or environment variables affecting the linker?

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR As mentioned above, what does `ls /lib64/libsfml-graphics.*` print? Now that you are trying our suggestion what is the latest command line that you are using?

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR What effects the linker is where your libraries are installed, and what options you use when compiling. That's why you need to be totally explicit about these things.

Comment: really sorry, I just know what the questions means, the print is `/lib64/libsfml-graphics.so`

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR OK then I think you need to use the `--shared` option when you link. You have shared libraries installed (that's what `.so` means), but you are trying to link as if you have static libraries installed (I'm no expert though)

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR Of course another option (maybe simpler) would be to install the static libraries (I assume SFML has both kinds of library).

Comment: still have the same output as before, how sad
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-system: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main7.coo: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR OK, I give up, when you try something new, please **quote exactly** the new command line that you are using. No-one here want's to guess what you are doing.

Comment: alright, alright I understand, new to stackoverflow btw here is what do I do with that output:
`g++ -L/lib64 -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system main7.coo -o main7 -shared`

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR My advice to use `-shared` was wrong, sorry about that. I would start with the command line described on the [official site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link) plus `-L/lib64` before the first `-l` option. Remember with g++ the order in which you give different options in important

Comment: `g++ -L/lib64 -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system main7.cpp -o main7`
like this? if yes it's still have the same output as before

Comment: Do you have a file anywhere called `sfmlXXX.pc` ? You could run `find / -name "sfml*.pc"` If you find that, you can use `pkgconfig` to tell you the compile/link switches automagically like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510642/2836621

Comment: first I tried to install the pkg-config 
`sudo dnf install pkg-config`
and then
`pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-graphics`
with print
`-I/usr/include/sysprof-6 -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`
and then
`g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-graphics) -o main`
and back to
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: ..` again...

Comment: and btw this print
`find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-system.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-window.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-network.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-all.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-audio.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sfml-graphics.pc`
is printed out when I type this
`sudo find / -name "sfml*.pc"`

Comment: Try using `sfml-all.pc` so you can use all of SFML, i.e. `g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-all) -o main`

Comment: `g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-all.oc) -o main` ?
problem still persist..

Comment: Please run the command from your question again, but add `-v` this time, and [edit] the question to include its output.

Comment: done, check it up

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `fedora,` but running a Docker image of `fedora:latest`, I did just the following steps on a bare, new Fedora installation and it compiles and links fine.

Start Docker image of fedora:

```
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/work fedora:latest
```

Inside fedora container:

```
sudo dnf install g++ pkg-config SFML-devel
cd /work
g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sfml-all) -o program
```

---

If your system doesn't compile with those steps, I would remove and reinstall those three packages.

Comment: how do I get the main.cpp, meanwhile the main.cpp is not inside the dock?

Comment: @SITUKANGGAMBAR You shouldn't use Docker (the answerer did just to test it on Fedora without installing it on the machine), but rather fix whatever is wrong with your Fedora installation.

Comment: Well, with reinstalled those 3 packages the problem still resists, is it possible that the causes was that I using fedora version 39? (not a stable release yet, they said it will released in 7 November after delaying from 1 November).

Answer (score 0):

I just try on myself, reinstall the package, just install the non-C packages and then tried to run this command:
`g++ sfml.cpp -o prog -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`
and it's work!

I Just followed this guy instructions:
https://youtu.be/5aWMIpRiuww?si=EHxkKw0nxYdc18D1

Comment: I don't understand, what did you end up reinstalling?

Comment: the sfml package itself, but just the regular SFML not for C languange